# API Management JWT with invalid child element issuer-signing-keys

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to set a validate-jwt token policy on my test instance of API Magement and I keep getting the following error:

**Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 15, column 10: The element 'validate-jwt' has invalid child element 'issuer-signing-keys'. List of possible elements expected: 'required-claims'.**

Here is the policy I am using:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
        <issuers>
            <issuer>https://myissuer.com</issuer>
        </issuers>
        <issuer-signing-keys>
            <key>dGVzdF9rZXk=</key>
        </issuer-signing-keys>
        <required-claims>
            <claim name="oid" match="all" />
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>
```

The key is just a test but it a valid 64 encoded value.

Is there any order in which the elements should be set? or any dependency on other elements? I could not find anything about this in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems the the https on the issuer was the error...it worked after removing it